# How do i use atoms for path variables in Apache http mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do i use the path variables in the source URL to redirect using apache mod_rewrite? In a nutshell,

This works

```
RewriteRule ^/?sourceURL/path/var1/(.*)$ http://destination/path?var1=$1 [L]
```

But this doesn't.

```
RewriteRule ^/?sourceURL/path/?var1=(.*)$ http://destination/path?var1=$1 [L]
```

**CONTEXT**

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can not match against url `QueryString` in pattern of a RewriteRule. You need to use a `RewriteCond` directive .

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var1=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?sourceURL/path/?$ http://destination/path?var1=%1 [L,R]
```